# Preference UI Components without PrefernceActivity

Tags: android

Is there a way to use the ui Components from the preference package without a PreferenceActivity?

I have to build a lot of settingsviews, and i cant use sharedprefernces.

Do i Have to build this all by hand?

Vino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the ui Components from the preference package without a PreferenceActivity?

Preferences are built using normal widgets, such as `ListView`, `CheckedTextView`, etc.

You cannot use subclasses of `Preference` outside of `PreferenceActivity`, though.

> I have to build a lot of settingsviews

Use `SharedPreferences` and `PreferenceActivity` for user settings.

> Do i Have to build this all by hand?

Apparently, yes. Then again, most quality Android applications' user interfaces are built "by hand".